# TypeScript > 4.1 Fixed Length String Literal Type

Tags: string, typescript, string-literals

The TypeScript team has been doing great work on string literal typing in recent updates (4.1 & 4.2). I am wondering if there is a way to type a fixed length string.

Ex.

```
type LambdaServicePrefix = 'my-application-service';
type LambdaFunctionIdentifier = 'dark-matter-upgrader';
type LambdaFunctionName = `${LambdaServicePrefix}-${LambdaFunctionIdentifier}`; // error: longer than 32 characters...
```

How I imagine it would go is something like, `Array<64, string>;`. TypeScript has the Tuple type so as an array I could fix length of an array. `[string, ... string * 62, string]`.

```
type FutureLambdaIdType = `${LambdaServicePrefix}-${string[32]}`;
```

Comment: Oof, I'm guessing this would be easy enough if TS didn't have such shallow recursion limits.  Everything I'm trying peters out well before you get to length 64 strings.  Maybe I can brute force it but it will be *uuuuugly*

Comment: Right now the closest I can get is [this](https://tsplay.dev/Qmbg4W).  Interested in having that written up or are you holding out hope for something different?

Comment: I appreciate the effort on your example, hopefully they'll add this functionality to TypeScript someday, I think I will just manually confirm the length, AWS yells at you at runtime. I assumed it was not possible to achieve what I wanted, but hoped there might be a solution.

@jcalz Do you know if your infer solution could throw an error if the string was too long?

Comment: There's no "invalid type" or "throw types" as requested by [microsoft/TypeScript#23689](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23689), so I can't write something that will just cause a compiler error if a string *type* is longer than 32 characters.  But if we are allowed to do things with values you can get errors, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/KwX3VW).  Does *that* work for you?  If so I'll write it up, although you seem to have accepted a different answer already.

Comment: Also, you might want to go to [microsoft/TypeScript#41160](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41160) to describe your use case, since they are trying to figure out if and how much people actually need regex-validated string types

Comment: Yeah my bad I meant a typescript compiler error like you have for any other situation in typescript. If you write up a solution that causes that compiler error, I will mark that as the accepted answer.

Comment: It looks like your example was actually doing what I was thinking too.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**UPDATED to reflect better recursive conditional type support**

There are still, as of TS 4.7, no regular-expression-validated string types in TypeScript.  [Template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) handle some, but not all, of the use cases for such regex types.  If you have a situation like this where template literal types are insufficient, you might want to go to [microsoft/TypeScript#41160](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41160) and describe your use case.  The idea of a "string whose maximum length is `N` characters" for some `N extends number` would be easy enough to express with regex types, but is not easily achievable with template literals.

Still, let's see how close we can get.

---

A major roadblock stands in the way.  TypeScript cannot easily represent the set of all strings less than `N` characters as a specific type `StringsOfLengthUpTo<N>`.  Conceptually any given `StringsOfLengthUpTo<N>` is a large [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types), but since the compiler balks at unions with more than ~10,000 members, you can only describe strings of up to a few characters this way.  Assuming you want to support the 95 characters of 7-bit printable ASCII, you will be able to represent `StringsOfLengthUpTo<0>`, `StringsOfLengthUpTo<1>`, and even `StringsOfLengthUpTo<2>`.  But `StringsOfLengthUpTo<3>` would exceed the compiler's capacity, since it would be a union of over 800,000 members.  So we have to give up on *specific* types.

---

Instead we can think of our type as a *constraint* used with [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html).  We need  a type like `TruncateTo<T, N>` which takes a type `T extends string` and an `N extends number` and returns `T` truncated to `N` characters.  Then we can constrain `T extends TruncateTo<T, N>` and the compiler would automatically warn on too-long strings.

It used to be that shallow recursion limits would prevent us from writing `TruncateTo<T, N>` for `N` greater than about 20 or so, but TypeScript 4.5 introduced support for [tail recursion elimination on conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#tail-recursion-elimination-on-conditional-types).  That means we can write `TruncateTo<T, N>` by adding some extra *accumulator* arguments like this:

```
type TruncateTo<T extends string, N extends number,
    L extends any[] = [], A extends string = ""> =
    N extends L['length'] ? A :
    T extends `${infer F}${infer R}` ? (
        TruncateTo<R, N, [0, ...L], `${A}${F}`>
    ) :
    A
```

This works by having an `A` accumulator to store the string we're building up, and an `L` arraylike accumulator that keeps track of how long that `A` string is (string literal types don't have a strongly typed `length` property, see [ms/TS#34692](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34692) for the relevant request).  We build up `A` one character at a time until we either run out of the original string, or until we reach a length of `N`.  Let's see it in action:

```
type Fifteen = TruncateTo<"12345678901234567890", 15>;
// type Fifteen = "123456789012345"

type TwentyFive = TruncateTo<"123456789012345678901234567", 25>;
// type TwentyFive = "1234567890123456789012345"
```

---

We can't directly write `T extends TruncateTo<T, N>` as TypeScript complains that this is a circular constraint.  But we can at least write a helper function like this:

```
const atMostN = <T extends string, N extends number>(
    num: N, str: T extends TruncateTo<T, N> ? T : TruncateTo<T, N>
) => str;
```

and then you could call `atMostN(32, "someStringLiteral")` and it would either succeed or warn based on the the length of the string literal argument.  Note that the `str` input is of a weird conditional type, whose sole purpose is to avoid the circular constraint.  `T` is inferred from `str`, and then checked against `TruncateTo<T, N>`.  If it succeeds, great.  Otherwise, we give `str` the type of `TruncateTo<T, N>`, and we'll see an error message.  It works like this:

```
const okay = atMostN(32, "ThisStringIs28CharactersLong"); // okay
type Okay = typeof okay; // "ThisStringIs28CharactersLong"

const bad = atMostN(32, "ThisStringHasALengthOf34Characters"); // error!
// -------------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// '"ThisStringHasALengthOf34Characters"' is not assignable to parameter of type 
// '"ThisStringHasALengthOf34Characte"'.
type Bad = typeof bad; // "ThisStringHasALengthOf34Characte"
```

---

Is it worth it? Maybe.  The original answer here had to do some unsavory things to get even a fixed-length check.  The current one isn't so bad, but it's still a bunch of effort to get a compile-time check.  So you might still have a use case for regex-validated string types.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgTgVwHYGMCGwIwPYB4ZQQAemSAJgM5QXBwCWSA5gDRQByhJE5VSCAtgCMIcZgFgAUFGlQAMp1KUoaJCADaAXSgBeKJtYBBBdyU16THVABEVgHw7JM9sZ5y1AcgA23RsAAW7loA-FBGAFyOMgTEilQABgAkAN4MAGYiUABiAL7JaRkAStlxUCEAFJFO0vDI6Jg4uAWsbKxqAAysAHTdshqsiUkGuUk5cbaVUACUUBFSMgaSkqCQWXSpmNyWNagYWHhWAIwATADMACwArABsAOwAHACcbcfn1-dPVqwHF7YA3JIAegBUGW0Eyaw2SEsh1Ol1uj2esIuVkWElBsAA7txQOCAG7QXTbOp7XAw17wp4vOHvRHkm6fKBHH6-KBAqDYADWaBAgOB6JgWKQOLo+OhVLeCPFFNplxREkkKGwSBoymAAFlsDQOLp8C5TLQGCxnDETLwBMI4LYKnNpHx+GF2KwzA7olxXETdg0YM17CECC7EDt6nhvexxhJptp7GZ-vKJIrlcB2VyQJYMBqtWUTkdWFYYH46BQAMoGpgASQoRzuAGE-Gg4GgUJg4BRZErGFZJrH0QB5FOWUHYVLJ7kstl5gvF0uMCtV2v1xvN1vtuUKpUqwRoMhp9Wa4BsLM56z5wsl8yMAASaAoBlkPn8PdS53nDabIgonbHwJEcGwcAAhLyUAALSgWB4EQeB9gAH6wXB8EIYhSHIUB7gTqe05Xjed5MA+T5nC+i7vlY7hQIWUBINgSbXhQdCMEgaCCN4ILYFAYALvwEDNuyw7oqh6FTueWG3vefiPs+davpgJGdEs4DQAAQluA7yUOUCbmQX7HpOZ6GsJOG+GJ+GEW+q5xqikhAA)

Comment: Thanks for the incredible work, I commented on that issue, in my head it doesn't feel like it should be that hard to define a certain length for a string since it is just a sequence of characters and we already have tuple types which are fixed length arrays essentially.

Comment: Sure, but there’s no built in “split” or “join” for string literal and tuple types, and if you build them yourself you hit recursion and/or union limits pretty quickly.  String literals also don’t have a strongly typed length property, so there’s no easy handle to turn here.

Answer (score 9):

There is no way to represent fixed-length strings with Typescript. There is a [very upvoted proposal here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6579), but still this feature has not been released.

If the length is very little, there are some workarounds suchs as the following:

```js
type Char = 'a'|'b'|'c'|'d'|'e'|'f'|'g'|'h'|'i'|'j'|'k'|'l'|'m'|'n'|'o'|'p'|'q'|'r'|'s'|'t'|'u'|'v'|'w'|'x'|'y'|'z'
type String3 = `${Char}${Char}${Char}`
const a: String3 = 'aa'    // error
const b: String3 = 'bbbbb' // error
const c: String3 = 'ccc'   // OK
const d: String3 = 'abc'   // OK
```

But you can't handle big lengths since you will run into a "Expression produces a union type that is too complex to represent" error.

Answer (score 1):

```
type IsThirteen<T extends number> = 13 extends T ? true : never
type IsFifteen<T extends number> = 15 extends T ? true : never

type LengthOfString<S extends string, T extends string[] = []> = S extends `${string}${infer R}`
  ? LengthOfString<R, [...T, string]>
  : T['length'];

type IsLengthThirteenOrFifteen<T extends string> = true extends IsThirteen<LengthOfString<T>>
    ? T
    : true extends IsFifteen<LengthOfString<T>>
        ? T
        : never

function IsLengthThirteenOrFifteenGuard <T extends string>(a: IsLengthThirteenOrFifteen<T>) {
  return a;
}

const b = IsLengthThirteenOrFifteenGuard('1131111111111')
```

Sources:

- [StringOfLength](https://github.com/doox911-opensource/typescript/blob/main/type-challenges/medium/Length_of_String.md)
- [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgzgFQBYEsBOwIQHYB4FQQAem2AJnFNgK4C2ARhGgHxQC8UAjAMyEk4UoBAPxRgaatABcVCADcmAWABQoSLDgAxFADNMOfH1KCaDJqw6cArEYGURYidNkK0KlWugAZHAHNgSADyOgDK4ijYvrghtuSUcOGRADRCsYIJaBG%20ANoAuuxQeRZQMcTGlAAGACQA3hlZAL61ETpMUABKDRUqUFCiPpEBwWGZkbjtKdkAdDMIKfWRucw9UDII2QDkADZ%20ARu5ANzuquDQ8AP%20SMjo%20tiBaNp6WHgEZXZQC77F4pJplPDXDDPXAXIahRJRBDMZbKXq9UQIFa9GQ-aBvOIaR63EG7ILg0aQ6FIuHwoTEkkybDyJTKFQ6ajYADGwBQAHtsBpQVdUECcPcsc8AOLUACGaDIUEM6PSEOYAAoRTJzrjAbd%20bpsVCAJRQGorNAQYDUNAckVHZQNY6M9kJKD0ArKwbcm7PdVPHDCsVkOUbTgAJm4ABYrAA2ADsAA4AJycAAMnE4Gy1QA)

Answer (score -2):

It is impossible to limit the length of string by typing or typescript utils.

You can, however, use regex to validate the string (including length):

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]){1,64}$/
```