# Typescript template literals type force structure

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```
type Foo<T extends string = string> = `bar-${T}-foo`;

const v: Foo = 'bar-g-foo'
```

That works as expected, but it doesn't force the structure. The following is also valid:

```
  const v: Foo = 'bar--foo'
```

How can I force the usage of `T`?

Comment: I was hoping ```type Foo<T extends string = string> = T extends "" ? never : `bar-${T}-foo`;``` would work (or perhaps without the default), but sadly, no. With the default, the type just ends up being `string`, and without the default, you have to explicitly provide the type parameter, and [while doing that works](https://tsplay.dev/NBkZDm), those aren't the ergonomics you want. :-|

Comment: why are you using the default? did you try without it?

Comment: As @T.J.Crowder said - "those aren't the ergonomics you want"

Comment: Similar question, but i don't think this is possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66212384/typescript-4-1-fixed-length-string-literal-type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is to **check for an empty string**. Read more about this problem here: [How to write a string type that does not contain an empty string in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46253340/how-to-write-a-string-type-that-does-not-contain-an-empty-string-in-typescript)

Based on the stack from above you could do something like this:

```
type Character = 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | ... ; // Here all possible 1 letter strings
type NonEmptyString = `${Character}${string}`;
type Foo<T extends string = NonEmptyString> = `bar-${T}-foo`;

const v: Foo = 'bar-a-foo' // ✔
const x: Foo = 'bar--foo' // ❌ Type '"bar--foo"' is not assignable to type
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgFgQwE4IMbAkqBeKByBPKAH3wCMjS9UiB6AKhKgDpX7aBuAKFEigDkA9gDsAogFswoAMrAkAS2EBzHFAAGAEgDe8ZGgxIAvtoDOcxUsNruvaADFBggDwAVKBAAeGYQBMTUMwVlVSExSRlzZQA+VTUyZABabRdDBIAzR2suLlQRMygANwBGAC4oB0FVPHikBIR0xyIoKFpaKEAUchy84EKAJjKKqpq6slQGwTo2ztzhfIKAZgHHIcTxpubWqEAZcigXcGg8ACJh8cOieX9hQR6EExN5JWEEMgAbaGBK2yA)

Comment: This is limited to one char

Comment: @undefined - No, it isn't: https://tsplay.dev/mAyZkm

Comment: The problem of course is defining that massive `Character` union with all the characters you want to allow, but with types *only* (no functions to get better inference), I don't think you'll do better than this.

Comment: I agree to @T.J.Crowder next problem now is to define an union with all single letter characters. Sadly typescript has not enough power to negate the type of `Type x = ""`. More about this here: https://catchts.com/type-negation

Answer (score 2):

It might not be the best approach, becasue of the reliance on the function assigning the value of generic type dynamically, but depending on your usage this could also be vallid

```
type NonEmptyString<T extends string> = T extends "" ? never : T;

function fn<T extends string>(a: `bar-${NonEmptyString<T>}-foo`) {
    // ...
}

fn("bar--foo"); // Error
fn("bar-g-foo"); // No error
fn("bar-gg-foo"); // No error
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9gOwKIFsygMrAE4EsEDmAPACpQQAewECAJgM5T074EB8UAvFGZdXYwBEgqAH4oCCADcI2KAC4eAbgBQKgGYBXBAGNguRFHUJS5KjQZMWhNgAoAhooAGAI3vYAtABIA3vGRomNbEJGwAvh7qcHBOAJRQPipQyVAA9KlQAHTZKmFqxraCbp6R0YKxSmkZSNjYcNgaCIXFHgSlcOWV6bBw5LX1jc3urW1RHRVVPX11QA)

Comment: I was struggling to come up with a function solution. Nice!